# There is a HTTP server starts when Launching Spark jar on a machine, what's that?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use machine A where I will submit my Spark job to the cluster, A has no spark environment, just java. When I launch the jar, there is a HTTP server starts：

```
[steven@bj-230 ~]$ java -jar helloCluster.jar SimplyApp
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-local-20140610165454-4393
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1055.1 MB.
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO ConnectionManager: Bound socket to port 59981 with id = ConnectionManagerId(bj-230,59981)
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager bj-230:59981 with 1055.1 MB RAM
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO HttpBroadcast: Broadcast server started at http://10.10.10.230:59233
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-bfdd02f1-3c02-4233-854f-af89542b9acf
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO SparkUI: Started Spark Web UI at http://bj-230:4040
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR hdfs://master:8020/tmp/helloCluster.jar at hdfs://master:8020/tmp/helloCluster.jar with timestamp 1402390494838
14/06/10 16:54:54 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master spark://master:7077...
```

So, what's the meaning of this server? And if I am behind a NAT, is it possible to use this machine A to submit my job to remote cluster?

By the way, the result of this execution is failed. Error log:

```
14/06/10 16:55:05 INFO SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor app-20140610165321-0005/7 removed: Command exited with code 1
14/06/10 16:55:05 ERROR AppClient$ClientActor: Master removed our application: FAILED; stopping client
14/06/10 16:55:05 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster! Waiting for reconnection...
14/06/10 16:55:11 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory
```

Comment: Did you set the master for your SparkConf? and closed the SparkContext that you declared?

Comment: @eliasah `val sc = new SparkContext(
    "spark://master:7077",
    "Simple App",
    "/opt/spark-0.9.1-bin-cdh4",                     //spark home
    List("hdfs://master:8020/tmp/helloCluster.jar") //jar location
  )`  I don't understand what's the meaning of closed SparkContext?

Comment: By the end of the app, you have to put sc.stop() so the App can terminate correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spark driver starts few HTTP endpoints:

- It provides a Web console that shows the job progress. This http endpoint has a default port of 4040 and can be changed with the configuration option: `spark.ui.port`. Then, you  connect to it with your browser: `http://your_host:4040`  and you will be able to follow the job. It's only alive the time the driver runs.
- There's an additional HTTP endpoint to provide a file download service for the jars declared as dependencies. The workers will contact the driver to download the list of dependencies. This is a random assigned port. Therefore, the driver must be on a routable network from the Spark workers.

Comment: Is it possible to submit job to a remote cluster using a machine behind NAT?

Comment: I tried to answer to that by saying "the driver must be on a routable network from the Spark workers". For remote job submittion we are trying SparkJobServer: https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver